# What is the number of inclusive relations?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations

A binary relation on a set T is inclusive if every element in T relates to at least one element.

As an example we can say that {(2, 3), (3, 4)} is not inclusive since 4 does not relate to any element.

So, what is the number of inclusive relations on an n-set for n = 1, 2, 3 and for arbitrary n?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: An inclusive relation on $A=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ assigns to each $k\in A$ a non-empty subset of $A$. How many non-empty subsets does $A$ have?

Comment: Do you think that the number of inclusive relations on an n-set is 2^n - 1?

Comment: @user115289: No, that’s the number of possible choices for the set of things related to a particular member of $A$.

Comment: But 2^n is the power set including the empty set, so 2^n -1 is the number of non-empty subsets

Comment: @user115289: Yes. And any one of those non-empty subsets can be the set of things to which a given $a\in A$ is related.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of your answer is not correct

Comment: @user115289: For $k\in A$ let $R[k]=\{a\in A:\langle k,a\rangle\in R\}$; you want the number of relations $R$ such that each $R[k]$ is non-empty. There are $2^n-1$ choices for each $R[k]$. How many $R[k]$’s are there?

Comment: Can you tell me an example please?

Comment: @user115289: Not without essentially doing the problem outright. It’s a simple application of the [multiplication principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). You have to choose $R[k]$ for each $k\in A$. You know how many different choices are available for each $R[k]$, and you know that $|A|=n$. How many ways are there to construct the whole relation $R$? Try constructing all of the inclusive relations when $n=2$; there are $9$ of them.